# Adding new pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new with Next js, and I'm adding a new page, I just create a folder `pages` inside of `src/app`, then I add file `dashboard.tsx` but when I try to go to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` I have this issue:

`404 | This page could not be found.`

why??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using app directory feature of NextJS 13. To make `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` work the file structure should be

`app/dashboard/page.tsx`

`dashboard` = a folder 
`page.tsx` = file, the page content, basically what you have in dashboard.tsx put it in this file

You can check for differences here https://blog.logrocket.com/next-js-13-app-directory/#page-directory-vs-app-directory

Comment: @JhonEstrada cannot understand why you just marked the other answer as accepted where this one is whats working for you

Answer (score 0):

The root file of a directory is `index.tsx`

**Edit**

As pointed out by another answer, you are using Next 13 and the `app` folder feature.

The page you are aiming to create should be `app/dashboard/index.tsx`

(not as previously mentioned `pages/dashboard/index.tsx` — which however would apply if you are pre-Next 13 or are opting out of the app folder)

Comment: I'm getting `404
This page could not be found.` yet

Comment: even if I just test witn `pages/index.tsx` don't work, I get the same issue.... this is a little strange